# available on this Friday vs available this Friday

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I usually add preposition after "available". For example, "I'm available on this Friday". But, I saw some people say 'I'm available this Friday'.

What is a difference between the sentences below? Is the meaning same?

- I'm available on this Friday
- I'm available this Friday.

Comment: Although results on a Google search seem even more bewildering than usual, I'd say 'I'm available on this Friday' is non-idiomatic as a variant of 'I'm available this Friday'. It would only be used in the context of say 'I'm looking at the last week in July ... I'm available on this Friday'. // 'I'm available on Friday' is probably the most common choice in the UK, while the 'on' might well be dropped in the US.

Comment: Fwiw, I have heard (and said) "I'm available *this* Friday" and "I'm available *on* Friday", but I have never once heard somebody say "I'm available *on this* Friday" (AmE, Northeast US).

Comment: I've never thought 'I'm available on this Friday' can be a problem if 'I'm available on Friday' is correct. How about 'I'm available Friday'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard the phrasing *"I'm available **on** this Friday"* before.

The preposition is implied in the sentence "I'm available this Friday".

Likewise, you can say, "This Friday, I'm ...".

You do not need to say "*On* this Friday, I'm ...". This wording may confuse your meaning, since the phrase "This Friday" has a widely understood meaning in itself rendering a preposition redundant. (There is a question illustrating this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36419/next-friday-vs-this-friday)).

You can also say "I'm available on Friday", if it's clear from context which Friday you are referring to. For example, if you were discussing availability for a particular week.

Comment: Hello. remnant. Note that in choosing not to supply supporting evidence, I considered that an 'answer' here was not justified. Though I did cover most of your points. And others.

Comment: Hello @EdwinAshworth, I understand you're saying that you considered an answer not justified here without providing evidence. I am new to stackexchange and your comment caused me to investigate the answers vs comments distinction, which I wasn't aware of. I also note that your initial comment here shortly preceded my answer and covered an angle that, in hindsight, may well have been relevant. My apologies if I've broken one or more rules in this case, and/or if I've misunderstood your above comment. Thanks for the feedback.